# Harmonic Oscillator (2DOF) - Do these results seem correct?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency, resonance

I solved a 2DOF system for a buried harmonic oscillator with a forcing function, but I'm not sure what I should be seeing in terms of resonant frequency shift & velocity.
The resonant frequency of the object is 220 Hz which we see at zero, but I'm not sure why frequency shifts so much.
[image: Results in Question]

Equations of the system:

> $$
> \begin{split}
>  m_s \ddot{x}_s + R_{s1}\dot{x}_s + R_{2s}\left( \dot{x}_s  - \dot{x}_m\right) + K_{s1}x_s + K_{s2} \left( x_s - x_m \right)  &=& F_0e(i*omega*t) \\
>  m_m \ddot{x}_m + R_{m}\dot{x}_m - R_{2s}\left( \dot{x}_s  - \dot{x}_m\right) + K_{m}x_m - K_{s2} \left( x_s - x_m \right)&=&0 \\
> \dot{x}_s - v_s&=& 0 \\
> \dot{x}_m - v_m &=& 0
> \end{split}
> $$

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484560/2451

Comment: I solved and wrote the script in Matlab. It seems odd that the resonant frequency & and velocity would respectively increase and decrease at 0.01m but decrease and increase as depth increases.